# Create new .png Image in D

Tags: image, d

I am trying to create a .png image that is X pixels tall and Y pixels short.  I am not finding what I am looking for on dlang.org, and am struggling to find any other resources via google.

Can you please provide an example of how to create a .png image in D?

For example, `BufferedImage off_Image = new BufferedImage(100, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html is what I am looking for (I think), except in the D programming language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a little lib that can do this too. Grab png.d and color.d from here:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

```
import arsd.png;

void main() {
    // width * height
    TrueColorImage image = new TrueColorImage(100, 50);

    // fill it in with a gradient
    auto colorData = image.imageData.colors; // get a ref to the color array
    foreach(y; 0 .. image.height)
        foreach(x; 0 .. image.width)
        colorData[y * image.width + x] = Color(x * 2, 0, 0); // fill in (r,g,b,a=255)
    writePng("test.png", image); // save it to a file
}
```

Comment: The current version also requires arsd.core from that package, and must be linked to libz.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in standard library for image work but you should be able to use DevIL or FreeImage to do what you want. Both of them have Derelict bindings.

- [DevIL (derelict-il)](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-il)
- [FreeImage (derelict-fi)](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-fi)

Just use the C API documentation for either of them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard 2D or 3D graphics API in Phobos, nor there is something similar to the ImageIO API from Java. However, there are plenty of D libraries written by various individuals, as well as various bindings to C/C++ libraries that could aid you in what you are doing. I am sure you should be able to accomplish what you need by using some parts of the [GtkD](http://www.gtkd.org) .

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer an alternative to Adam's solution - [dlib](http://code.dlang.org/packages/dlib) has quite a few modules that come in handy when writing multi-media applications - image manipulation, linear algebra as well as geometry processing, I/O streams done right, basic XML parsing and others. It's still getting some development on the core interfaces (as of February 2014), but that should get pretty stable within a few weeks.

With dlib, that example code would translate to:

```
import dlib.image;

// width * height
auto image = new Image!(PixelFormat.RGB8)(100, 50);

// fill it in with a gradient
foreach(y; 0 .. image.height)
    foreach(x; 0 .. image.width)
        image[x, y] = Color4f(x * 2 / 255.0f, 0, 0);

savePNG(image, "test.png");
```

Grabbing the bytes directly is of course possible too, but why not do it the easier way? Premature optimization, etc.

If you're building your application with `dub` (which you probably should), using the latest and best of dlib is as simple as adding `"dlib": "~master"` to your `dependencies`.